# Materialize CSS dropdown doesn't work in Blazor (server side)

Tags: html, css, dropdown, materialize, blazor-server-side

I've built a "pure HTML" template using MaterializeCSS (https://materializecss.com).

Inside the template, I have a dropdown menu that shows up as expected after the click event.
My code is as follows:

```
<header>
<!-- Dropdown sub-menu -->
<ul id="dropdown-menu-profile" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">face</i>Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">login</i>Logout</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Navigation with main menu -->
<nav role="navigation">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li>
          <!-- Activator image where the data-target must match the dropdown's id --> 
          <a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown-menu-profile">
               <img class="avatar responsive-img" src="img/avatar.png">
           </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

For the Materialize to work I need to inject this script. All good so far.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown({ 
        hover: false,
        coverTrigger: false
      });
  });
```

[(The visual effect, after clicking)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipTTs.png)

However, when I move the HTML code to a Blazor server-side component, the very same "onclick->show dropdown" behavior is not working.

I don't have any errors and in the debugger window, both the "id" and "data-target" seem to have the same value. The same initialize javascript runs perfectly in the _Host.cshtml.

However, the dropdown simply doesn't appear when I click in the avatar image inside the Blazor component.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown({ 
        hover: false,
        coverTrigger: false
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    
<header>
<!-- Dropdown sub-menu -->
<ul id="dropdown-menu-profile" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">face</i>Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">login</i>Logout</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Navigation with main menu -->
<nav role="navigation">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <ul class="right">
        <li>
          <!-- Activator image where the data-target must match the dropdown's id --> 
          <a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown-menu-profile">
               <img class="avatar responsive-img" src="img/avatar.png">
           </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer!

I need to call the javascript on the OnAfterRenderAsync of the razor component!
Like this:

On the _Hosts.cshtml

```
<script>
        function WireDropdowns() {
            $(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown({
                hover: false,
                coverTrigger: false
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Then, on the Razor component:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("WireDropdowns", "");
    }

}
```

And it works! :-)